# How do I add woocommerce custom field shortcode in sprintf?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to add custom field shortcode in cart product name. Right now, I don't know how to display custom field  value, because the code is in sprintf.

I create a custom field in woocommerce product. The customs field is called color. I want the cart product name to print out the custom field value.

custom field shortcode

```
   <?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'color', true ); ?>
```

cart product name

```
                        <?php
                            if ( ! $_product->is_visible() ) {
                                echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', $_product->get_title(), $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) . '&nbsp;';
                            } else {
                                echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', sprintf( '<a class="items-info" href="%s">%s </a>', esc_url( $_product->get_permalink( $cart_item ) ), $_product->get_title() ), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
                            }

                        ?>
```

For example,

My product name is "New york tee" and my custom field color value is "white"
I want it to display like "New york tee - white" in my woocommerce cart product name. Also I want to add a dash before product name and custom field value. li
"New york tee - white"
Can someone help me? thank you.

Comment: Why not use a variable product? A white version (aka "variation") of "new york tee" is exactly the point of variable products.

Comment: i have one color for the product. Should i use one color for variable?

Comment: If you only have 1 color (and there will never be another), then why not just name the tshirt "New York Tee White"? But yes, you can use "color" as an attribute and then create 1 variation.

Answer (score 0):

You can add filter on `woocommerce_cart_item_name` to modify the title

```
function my_custom_cart_product_name_filter( $title, $item ) {
    $color = get_post_meta( $item['product_id'], 'color', true ); 
    return $color ? $title . sprintf(" Color - %s", $color) : $title;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', 'my_custom_cart_product_name_filter', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: Thanks. Do I place this code in my function.php? Do I have anything in other pages?

Comment: what is woocommerce_cart_item_name?

Comment: The color value is not displaying in my cart product name. I put the code you gave me in function.php. Did I do something wrong?